# Electron Window Will Only Open Once

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I am creating an Electron App and when I open a new window either using a button or from the file dropdown it will open the window fine. If I close that window and try to open it again nothing will appear.

My terminal gives the error
ERROR:ipc_channel_win.cc(414)] pipe error: 232
when closing the window.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>Advance</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>require('./main.js')</script>
    <div class="navBar">
        
    </div>
    <section>
        
        <div class="form-box">

            <h2>Claimant Information</h2>
            <script>
                var ipc = require('ipc') 
                var cInfoButton = document.createElement('button')
                cInfoButton.textContent = 'Amend'
                cInfoButton.name = "cInfoBtn"
                cInfoButton.addEventListener('click',function () {
                    console.log('clicked')
                    ipc.send('show-c_Info')
                })
                document.querySelector("div.form-box").appendChild(cInfoButton)


            </script>
            <div class="cInfo">
                <form action="">
                    <div class ="cName">
                        <label for="">Name</label> 
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" disabled>        
                    </div>
                    <div class ="cRef">
                        <label for="">Reference Number</label>
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" disabled>  
                    </div>
                    <div class ="cAdd">
                        <label for="">Address</label>
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" disabled>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <div class="form-box">
            <h2>Claim Circumstances</h2>
            <button type="button">Amend</button>
            <div class="cCircs">
                <form action="">
                    <div class="cBens">
                        <label for="">Benefits</label>
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" disabled>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

```
var app = require('app')
var Browserwindow = require('browser-window')
var ipc = require('ipc')

app.on('ready', function() {
    var mainWindow = new Browserwindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
    })
    mainWindow.loadUrl('file://' + __dirname + '/main.html')
    mainWindow.openDevTools()
    var prefsWindow = new Browserwindow({
        width: 400,
        height: 400,
        show: false
    })
    prefsWindow.loadUrl('file://' + __dirname + '/prefs.html')
    ipc.on('toggle-prefs', function (){
        if (prefsWindow.isVisible())
            prefsWindow.hide()
        else
            prefsWindow.show()

    })
    var c_InfoWindow = new Browserwindow({
        width: 400,
        height: 800,
        show: false
    })
    c_InfoWindow.loadUrl('file://' + __dirname + '/c_Info.html')
    ipc.on('show-c_Info', function (){
        c_InfoWindow.show()
    })
    var aboutWindow = new Browserwindow({
        width: 650,
        height: 500,
        show: false
    })
    aboutWindow.loadUrl('file://' + __dirname + '/About/about.html')
    //aboutWindow.openDevTools()
    ipc.on('open-about', function (){
           aboutWindow.show()
    })
})
```

I was hoping that I would be able to close and open the window as many times as I want.

FYI I am pretty new to Electron and coding in general I will do my best to answer any questions you have.